# Php retrieve query and use in If statment

Tags: php, if-statement, query-string

Ok, I am trying to do something that I would normally be able to do pretty easy in ASP but for some reason, despite reading documentation, I can figure out why this If statement is displaying my code.

I am trying to simply retrieve a query string of ?fs=success

IF true then display the html, if not do nothing.  Where am I going wrong as the page displays the code even if no query string is present.  Thanks

```
if ($_GET['fs'] = 'success') {
    echo "<div class='container'><div class='row configureCellSplitBG-ouline color-contrast-yellow text-center'><h3>THANK YOU</h3><p>We have recieved your message and will get back to you soon!</p></div></div>";
}
```

Comment: Change `if ($_GET['fs'] = 'success') {` to `if ($_GET['fs'] == 'success') {`. Notice the double equals `==`;

Comment: Always tough to tell with code fragments, but if it is displaying your php code on the screen you have to question if your code has actually run through a php processor.

Comment: thanks everyone.  just not very familiar with php.  Seriously, why did I get down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single = sets it, double equals checks value.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
if ($_GET['fs'] == 'success') {
```